# How to run CMD commands after running ftp file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am using a bat file to run a ftp file. Below is the start.bat content

```
ftp -s:runFtp.txt
moveFiles.bat
```

The moveFiles.bat has some move commands that are to work on my local machine after the ftp is complete.

Problem: 
When ftp is complete, the cmd window still shows being run in ftp> mode. And thus the moveFiles.bat is never getting executed. I am successfully able to run both separately but i need a single bat to perform both i.e first ftp and then uplon completion movefiles.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Add a `quit` at the end of *runFtp.txt*.

Comment: I already tried that. It closes whole thing.wont process the next bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the beginning of moveFiles.bat:

```
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C ftp -s:runFtp.txt
```

This will execute `ftp -s:runFtp.txt` in a new minimized enviroment and then automatically close itself while moveFiles.bat will wait for it to close.

Comment: Thanks a ton, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad I could help! :)